# Change a value in a binary file (C)

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fwrite

The program should change a specific value in a record, and I used fseek and fwrite to do so. But when I run it, it overwrites the next record.

Here's a part of my program :

```
j = 0;
while ((fread(&Rec, sizeof(Rec), 1, file) == 1) && (Found == 0))
{
    if (strcmp(Rec.Name, SearchName) == 0)
    {
        if (Rec.BD == SearchBD)
        {
            Found = 1;
            printf("\nEnter the new value : ");
            scanf("%f", &Val);

            fseek(file, (sizeof(Rec))*j, SEEK_SET);
            strcpy(Rec.Name, SearchName);
            Rec.BD = SearchBD;
            Rec.V = Val;
            fwrite(&Rec, sizeof(Rec), 1, file);

        }

    }

    j++;
}
```

Comment: String functions will not do well when evaluating content in a binary file.  The string functions only work with strings, i.e. char array terminated with a NULL character.  Without a NULL, the `strcmp` function will yield unexpected results.  ***[Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16365135/645128)*** for a conversation covering similar request.

Comment: Yeah, well, the types of Rec, Val etc. are missing so we don't know what is going on anyway.   The 'strcpy(Rec.Name, SearchName);' inside the 'if (strcmp(Rec.Name, SearchName)' block is somewhat pointless/worrying:(

Comment: @ryyker, if the binary was written fom the C structures, then they can be read-back without problem. The C structures, when written, will all contain null terminated character arrays, which will be read-back.

Comment: Although it doesn't solve the problem, the `while` must be written as `while ((Found == 0) && (fread(&Rec, sizeof(Rec), 1, file) == 1))` as otherwise there will be an extra `fread` after `found`

Comment: @MartinJames I know it's pointless, I was doing extra tests just in case ><

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code cannot overwrite the next record. The code is correct. However, if you use `Rec` further on in your program (you gave only a snippet), then you will find that `Rec` has unexpected values. That is because after the record searched for was found, the `while` loop performs one more `fread` before exiting the loop. That is because the `while` loop must be written as:

```
while ((Found == 0) && (fread(&Rec, sizeof(Rec), 1, file) == 1))
```

as otherwise another `fread` will be performed before `found` will be tested and the loop exited.